# DB engine error when using filters in apache superset dashboard

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-superset

I created a apache superset dashboard with some filters. When I try to use the filter to interact with the dashboard, I am getting a "DB engine error". The dashboard runs fine if the filters are not applied. The data is in Google Bigquery.

[image: DB_Engine_error_in_filter]